# Fold a big chunk of text in a question

Tags: support, questions, markdown, code-formatting

Is it possible to fold a big chunk of text in a question?

In my case I need to paste [this](https://pastebin.com/c6Hu4nV5) HTML into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649874/aspose-pdf-textstamp-overlaps-with-the-previously-added-text-how-is-it-possible) question.

I need this, because, the big chunk of text is relevant for the question, but is not directly related to the question. It is just required for the reproduction of a specific issue which I am asking about.

Comment: Which specific problems did you face when trying?

Comment: So again: **Why** can't you paste it into your question?

Comment: "the big chunk of text is relevant for the question, but is not directly related to the question" ... so relevant, but not related ... huh? What do you mean by that?

Comment: *"It is just required for the repoduction of a specific issue"* ... well, is it really? You're asking about text added via a Java function which when overlaps with the text inside a HTML file. So why do you need the images in that file? Also, you use the Java method to create page numbers, but you don't need to do that in your example, you can create them somewhere else where you need a lot less "foos" to fill space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really think that blob of HTML is 100% needed and useful for the experts to have, include it in a code-snippet.

```html
<html style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';"><head><style type="text/css">table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} table{border-collapse: collapse;}</style></head><body style="margin-top:4.5em; margin-bottom:4.5em; margin-left:4em; margin-right:4em;"><div><div align="center" style='font-size:16pt;'>АРКУШ ПОГОДЖЕННЯ</div></div><div><div style='font-size:15pt; margin-bottom: 8px; color: #666666' align="center"><div>Вхідний </div><div>№9250</div><div></div><div>в. 1</div></div></br></br></div><div><table style='font-size:11pt; float:center; margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 8px;' cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" ><tr><td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'></td><td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 14:43<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b></td><td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'><img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></td><td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'><span style='word-break: break-all;'><b>: </b><i>foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo</i></span></td></tr><tr><td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'></td><td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 14:43<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b></td><td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'><img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></td><td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'><span style='word-break: break-all;'><b>: </b><i>foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo</i></span></td></tr><tr><td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'></td><td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 14:43<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b></td><td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'><img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></td><td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'><span style='word-break: break-all;'><b>: </b><i>foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo</i></span></td></tr><tr><td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'></td><td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 15:03<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b></td><td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'><img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></td><td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'></td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'><span style='word-break: break-all;'><b>: </b><i>dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</i></span></td></tr></table></div><br><div style='font-size:11pt; margin-top: 8px;'><i>Станом на 10.01.2020 18:40:16. <br>Підписано файли: </i></div></body></html>
```

That has the added benefit it can be run on demand while it doesn't take up all the screen estate.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the missing linebreaks there seems to be no problem with the mere length so far.

> Is it possible to fold a big chunk of text in a question?

No, there's no such feature in the markdown editor.

I'd recommend to load it in a decent text editor, having a HTML pretty print feature, use that and then copy / paste the text, and code format it for markdown.

Here are my results using the Notepad++ XML-Plugin pretty print with line breaks feature:

```
<html style="font-family: 'Times New Roman';">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;} table{border-collapse: collapse;}</style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top:4.5em; margin-bottom:4.5em; margin-left:4em; margin-right:4em;">
        <div>
            <div align="center" style='font-size:16pt;'>АРКУШ ПОГОДЖЕННЯ</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style='font-size:15pt; margin-bottom: 8px; color: #666666' align="center">
                <div>Вхідний </div>
                <div>№9250</div>
                <div/>
                <div>в. 1</div>
            </div>
        </br>
    </br>
</div>
<div>
    <table style='font-size:11pt; float:center; margin-top: 12px; margin-bottom: 8px;' cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr>
            <td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'/>
            <td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 14:43<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b>
                    </td>
                    <td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'>
                        <img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
                        </td>
                        <td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'>
                            <span style='word-break: break-all;'>
                                <b>: </b>
                                <i>foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo</i>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'/>
                        <td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 14:43<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b>
                                </td>
                                <td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'>
                                    <img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'/>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'>
                                        <span style='word-break: break-all;'>
                                            <b>: </b>
                                            <i>foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo</i>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'/>
                                    <td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 14:43<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'>
                                                <img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'/>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'>
                                                    <span style='word-break: break-all;'>
                                                        <b>: </b>
                                                        <i>foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofo</i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="40%" align="left" style='word-break: break-word;'/>
                                                <td colspan="2" width="35%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'>08.01.2020 15:03<br>ПІДПИСАНО КЕП<b>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="5%" align="center" style='border-right: 0px;'>
                                                            <img width="40%" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM4AAACkCAYAAADfcBH4AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAFiUAABYlAUlSJPAAAAoYSURBVHhe7d1riFzlHcdxa1MNRajQQluQUqHQy5sW2hd9UcQXvvCVaJOUtNo2pa21VCFiWmwJBBEV1BKI2IASDEoIaEvcTTZpE0MiazS65GJza1y7mmwu2KxubGLWbEyf5jc5M+zsPHM5Z87luXy/8EfUJLvPmfPJ7Jx5ZuYKQ0SpAw5RhoBDlCHgkNdd+N8n5rUPDpv1J0fMM0e2mgcPP2+WHVpb+6f+fdN7u83I5Gjt1+UZcMi7JqfPmueObjcLRx4312xYaK548dau84WNPzN37Fpu1h4bNmcuTCV/UvaAQ940evaEWbR7hZkzMM+Ko9eZO7jALN63ypz8eDL5k9MHHHI+neA60fsFM3v6AQQccroXju/o+cexrHPt0O21x0JpAg45mx7k2070Ikb3Zo+Nrku+cveAQ86lB+/z33jUeoIXPXoM1csVOOCQUwnND4b/aD2pyxpdfesWcMiZXEBTHz0P1CngkBO5hEajxzx6UrVdwKHKcw1NfXQ1752P3ku+y+aAQ5XmKpr66GKBLeBQZbmORqMf2bRjYXbAoUryAU19bPc6wKHS8wmNRvc64+cmku/+csChUvMNTX2eGBtKVnA54FBp+YpGc9OOZckqLgccKiWf0Wi0k1prqAccKjzf0dRn3YmdyYqAQwUXChrN0+9uTlYFHCqwkNBo9DKHesChQgoNjeauvSuT1QGHCihENJqZT4QCh3ItVDQa4FAhhYxGs/TgmmSlwKGcCh2NZvnbg8lqgUM5FAMajd4EsR5wqK9iQaOZ+aI24FDmYkLznW33Jqu+HHAoUzGh0cy8MKCAQ6mLDY1Gn4gwM+BQqmJEM/vHNAUc6rkY0WhsbxMFHOqpWNHc+MrS5Ag0BxzqWqxoNNtO7UuOQnPAoY7FjGbJ/tXJUWgNONS2mNHc/OoDHT+1ADhkLWY033jpd7X1dwo41FLMaL60aZE5dOZYciTaBxxqCjTd0SjgUCPQ9IZGAYdqgaZ3NAo4BJqUaBRwIg806dEo4EQcaLKhUcCJNNBkR6OAE2Gg6Q+NAk5kgaZ/NAo4EQWafNAo4EQSaPJDo4ATQaDJF40CTuCBJn80CjgBB5pi0CjgBBpoikOjgBNgoCkWjQJOYIGmeDQKOAEFmnLQKOAEEmjKQ6OAE0CgKReNAo7ngaZ8NAo4HgeaatAo4HgaaKpDo4DjYaCpFo0qHM7k9Nmmz06k/gJN9WhUbnC0oJXv/N0sHHncfG3Lb801Gxa2LFz//aYdy8xde1eadSd2mqmL08nvpl4CjRtoVF9wTn48aZYdWltblG2x3Ua47ti1vIao0xtcE2hcQqMywRGYxftWmbmDC6wLzTL6uLjhiYPJV6CZgcYtNCo1nOVvD5o5A/Osi8xj9KPe+LmJ5KsRaNxDo3qGowf5t77+iHWBeY9+hOPeBzSuolE9wRmZHDVf3XyndYFFje7VXji+I/kO4gs07qJRXeFoAbYrZGWNfjSMLdC4jUZ1hKOLAFqIbYFlTkx4QOM+GtUWjm5AfaSbbYFVzNPvbk6+s3ADjR9oVFs4urplW2BVE/pjHtD4g0ZZ4eiKlm2BVY/whHi1DTR+oVEtcPQMvp6MtC3ShdGFitc+OJx8t/4HGv/QqBY42m9mW6RL4/MBnxlo/L0NW+BoI6Ztoa6NDryu+vkaaPz+i68Jzp7TY9aFujq66ucjHtD4/9NCE5ylB9dYF+vyfP/lP9RORF8Cjf9oVBMcX35Mmz06EX14WQJowkCjGnBOnf/QumBfZv4bjzqNBzThoFENONrIaVu0T/OrPU8mq3Er0ISFRjXgrD02bF24b6MX2LkUaMJDoxpwHnnrb9bF+ziubAoFTZhoVAOOj1fUOk3Vm0JBEy4a1YCjN92wHQRfp8pNoaAJG41qwHlibMh6IHwevZlI2ZtCQRM+GtWA88yRrdaD4ftoU6iuGJYRaOJAoxpw1p8csR6QEKaMGxU08aBRDTi64Yt826eq57p//LKwfW2giQuNasBR2vdlOzihTBGbQkETHxrVBOf+A89aD1BIo5NcJ3segSZONKoJzpb/7LUepNDmxleW9r2vDTTxolFNcJTLL5vOc/rZFAqauNGoFjihXpa2jT5uJG2gAY1qgaO/hX19XU6WWbJ/dbLy7oEGNPVa4KiY7nU0vWwKBQ1oZmaFo8r6ZAJXRn9ZtAs0oJldWzj6WI+yP6Ggymm3KRQ0oLHVFo7SHq+QdxPMntmbQkEDmnZ1hKNC3DXdaeqbQkEDmk51haMeG11nPcChzhc3/tx8d/t91v8X+oCmt3qCo/RaftuBZsIZ0PRez3DUot0rrAec8X9Ak65UcPTkqLaq2A484++AJn2p4Kipi9PRPmgOcUCTrdRwlK44fW/7EusNwfgzoMleJjhKLwhz6TNCmXQDmv7KDEeNn5uo3QC2G4Zxd0DTf33BUboBwOPPgCaf+oajtE1Fz7jbbijGnQFNfuUCRwlPTPvafBvQ5FtucJR2F4PHvQFN/uUKR+nNzm03HlPNgKaYcoej9IpK243IlDugKa5C4Cg2hVY7oCm2wuAofbSg7UZlih3QFF+hcNgUWv6AppwKhaOEh02h5QxoyqtwOEqbQkN/Q/eqBzTlVgocxabQ4gY05VcaHCU8upFtNz6TbUBTTaXCUbqRwZPPgKa6Soej9PZLbArtb0BTbZXAUdoUqjcAtJ0UTOcBTfVVBkexKTT9gMaNKoWjYvtkhH4GNO5UORzFptDuAxq3cgKO0gc82U4YBjQu5gwcpY8WtJ04MQ9o3MwpOGwKbR7QuJtTcJTw6OPUbSdSTAMat3MOjor5s2k0oHE/J+GoU+c/jHJTKGj8yFk4SptCY/ocUtD4k9NwlE4knVC2Ey2kAY1fOQ9H7Tk9FvSmUND4lxdwVKhvswsaP/MGjgptUyho/M0rOOq5o9utJ6FvAxq/8w6O8n1TKGj8z0s46v4Dz1pPStcHNGHkLRx195tPWU9OVwc04eQ1HJ82hYImrLyGo4Tn5lcfsJ6srgxowst7OEqbQr+59W7rSVv1fH7jT0ETYEHAUZPTZ821Q7dbT96q5rPrfwSaQAsGjhqfmjBzL52stpO47Ll6cL7Z/98jyXdGoRUUHDX8/iHz6YEfWk/msuYzA/PMrtP/Tr4jCrHg4KiXTr1p5gxWszXnqkv3NMJLYRckHHXgzFHzuaGfWE/uokYXAg6fOZ58BxRywcJRumDw9ZJeRXrD8J/M1MXzyVem0AsaTr0H//W8uWpgvvWE73euHlxgHn7rr8lXoliKAo7SvcGPR/5srhy4zQog7eixzJ17/lJ7ApbiKxo49SYvfGQW/3OVuX7Lb8ynXkyH6MpLv/4rm39tfr9/NWAiLzo4M5u6OG1WjG0wt7z+sPn2tntrW2P0PJDuTXRh4cubfmG+tfUec8vOh8ya8ZeT30UUORyirAGHKEPAIcoQcIhSZ8z/AS/GSKAUwHhXAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td width="30%" align="left" style='word-break: break-all; border-left: 0px;'/>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="5" align="left" style='vertical-align: top;'>
                                                                <span style='word-break: break-all;'>
                                                                    <b>: </b>
                                                                    <i>dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</i>
                                                                </span>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <br>
                                                    <div style='font-size:11pt; margin-top: 8px;'>
                                                        <i>Станом на 10.01.2020 18:40:16. <br>Підписано файли: </i>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </body>
                                                </html>
```

There is a maximum limit of text (50.000 characters)  you can post in your question, but the chunk you have doesn't exceed that.

Though you should think over if it's really necessary to create a **minimal, reproducible example** for your question, or that could be replaced with some smaller chunk of text (howsoever that is relevant for your question).

Comment: Just FYI: The [last I checked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176445/knowing-your-limits-what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-question-title-post-image), the maximum number of characters in a question or answer was 30,000. Also, the SE snippet editor has a "Tidy" button on the left which will reformat the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, including adding linebreaks.

Comment: @Makyen The error message when trying said 50.000, unless I misread without glasses..

Answer (score 3):

Do you need the *entire* HTML text to be in your question?

This is one of the tenets of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - notably, the **M**.

> Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem

If you can reproduce the same problem with a tenth of the file, then use that, but try your hardest not to include too much.